# getting "No such file or directory" for a nonexistent command

Tags: linux, command-line, path

I uninstalled manually mpi from my machine, but now when I make the command mpirun I get "-bash: /usr/local/bin/mpirun: No such file or directory" rather than "-bash: mpirun: command not found". 
ps. before uninstalling mpi the mpirun was in the directory /usr/local/bin/

Does some one have an idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a not deleted symlink to a deleted symlink to the deleted binary or something like that. Did you try `which mpirun` to get to know what you are actually calling?

Comment: It could also be hashing issue in the current bash session. In this case issuing the `hash -r` command or starting a new shell would solve the problem.